# WooCommerce Multi-Step Checkout (Billing/Shipping Address and Payment Methods on different pages)

Tags: woocommerce, stripe-payments

I'm currently working on a multi STRIPE checkout for different STRIPE accounts based on the shipping country.
So far everything works smoothly by using the `wc_stripe_params`, `wc_stripe_payment_request_params` and `woocommerce_stripe_request_headers` filters and overloading the respective classes for the webhooks. There is one problem though.
Upon checkout page load, where the payment methods are, STRIPE renders CDATA values for their JS files.

When the initial shipping country guess through geoip database was correct and the customer doesnt change the shipping country, everything works fine, since the correct public keys were inserted into the JS of STRIPE. When the customer changes the shipping country there is no way to manipulate the already processed JS variables. This is why I want to split up the checkout process so that the last page is just for payment options based upon the before selected shipping country.

I know that there are multiple plugins for multi-step checkout available, but all use ajax for a smooth rendering, which results in the same error. I understand the way how to customize different processes in WP or WC, but I don't know how to really tackle this one since the `form`on the checkout page is posted to the `wc_get_checkout_url()` which needs payments selected and done - it doesnt look like there is a real multi step without ajax planned?

Thanks in advance for any help or thoughts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved by splitting up the checkout process into multiple forms and posting the data as one to the woocommerce checkout controller